# javascript onclick not working?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

i am trying to do simple stuff by uploading file then showing the name of the file in a

tag and it's not working,my code is:

```js
function smth () {
    var x=document.getElementById("myfile");
    var file=x.files[0];
    var txt="";
    txt=file.name;
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML =txt;
}
```

```html
<p id="p1"></p>
<input type="file" id="myfle">
<button onclick="javascript:smth()" value="clickme"></button>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly isn't working? And which browser? I tried it in chrome, I selected an image file, and the name showed after I selected it.

Comment: the p tag is  still empty even after i click the button,i am trying on chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong because the input id value is myfle and the documentgelementbyid was retrieving a non existing element called #myfile.See the fix below:

```
<p id="p1"></p>
<input type="file" id="myfile">
<button onclick="javascript:smth()" value="clickme"></button>

<script>
function smth () {
    var x = document.getElementById("myfile");
    var file = x.files[0];
    var txt="";
    txt=file.name;
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML =txt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: i wanted to put my reputation is less than 15

Comment: by accept you mean a vote up for the answer ,right?? am still new for stackoverflow

Comment: Understood. I'm glad to help you.

Comment: @aghed aljlad Could you accept my answer, not vote up?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'm noticing is that you've mistyped:

```
<input type="file" id="myfle">
```

myfle atleast should be myfile.